# В чем может быть причина краша?

Tags: android

Не могу понять в чем проблема. При запуске приложение крашится.

Ошибка:

```
                                                                          Process: com.georgcantor.newwallpaper, PID: 29709
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.georgcantor.newwallpaper/com.georgcantor.newwallpaper.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.georgcantor.newwallpaper.widget.ImageDetailView
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.georgcantor.newwallpaper.widget.ImageDetailView
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                              at com.georgcantor.newwallpaper.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:74)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                              at com.georgcantor.newwallpaper.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:74) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                                              at com.georgcantor.newwallpaper.widget.ImageDetailView.<init>(ImageDetailView.kt:176)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                              at com.georgcantor.newwallpaper.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:74) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                              at com.georgcantor.newwallpaper.widget.ImageDetailView.<init>(ImageDetailView.kt:176) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                              at com.georgcantor.newwallpaper.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:74) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: SimpleDraweeView was not initialized!
                                                                              at com.facebook.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:226)
                                                                              at com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView.init(SimpleDraweeView.java:81)
                                                                              at com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView.<init>(SimpleDraweeView.java:63)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                              at com.georgcantor.newwallpaper.widget.ImageDetailView.<init>(ImageDetailView.kt:176) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                              at com.georgcantor.newwallpaper.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:74) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: у вас xml разметки валиден?

Comment: вроде все норм с xml

Comment: так "вроде все норм" или **100% валиден** ?

Comment: а как узнать что он валиден?

Comment: На [en-so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36724822) говорят нужно инициализировать Fresco до вызова `setContentView()`

Comment: Да и стектрейс говорит тоже самое `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: SimpleDraweeView was not initialized!`

Comment: Спасибо помогло

Comment: сделал как на en-so